# Как на JS правильно конвертировать миллисекунды в формат 00:00:00,000?

Tags: javascript, время, utc

На компе стоит время в моем часовом поясе в миллисекундах 1679287353711 , (что равно 04:42:33,711 это я в экселе посчитал вот так: =(1679287353711/86400000)+ДАТА(1970;1;1)

Выполняю JS код чтоб преобразовать это время в формат и сохранить в переменную TIME_FORMAT в таком виде: 00:00:00,000

Но выдаёт: 02:42:33,711 вместо 04:42:33,711
Как правильно исправить ошибку без подгона ответа юзая вот это: hours + 2 ?

JS Код:

```js
var TIME = 1679287353711;
var date = new Date(TIME);
var hours = date.getUTCHours() + (date.getTimezoneOffset() / 60);
if (hours < 10) {
  hours = '0' + hours;
}
var minutes = date.getUTCMinutes();
if (minutes < 10) {
  minutes = '0' + minutes;
}
var seconds = date.getUTCSeconds();
if (seconds < 10) {
  seconds = '0' + seconds;
}
var milliseconds = date.getUTCMilliseconds();
if (milliseconds < 10) {
  milliseconds = '00' + milliseconds;
} else if (milliseconds < 100) {
  milliseconds = '0' + milliseconds;
}
TIME_FORMAT = hours + ':' + minutes + ':' + seconds + ',' + milliseconds;

console.log(TIME_FORMAT);
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19700358 на en-so есть ответ на похожий вопрос, посмотрите, возможно это то, что нужно

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для получения часов в вашем часовом поясе Вам нужно использовать метод `getHours()` вместо `getUTCHours()`

```js
var TIME = 1679287353711;
var date = new Date(TIME);
var hours = date.getHours();
if (hours < 10) {
  hours = '0' + hours;
}
var minutes = date.getMinutes();
if (minutes < 10) {
  minutes = '0' + minutes;
}
var seconds = date.getSeconds();
if (seconds < 10) {
  seconds = '0' + seconds;
}
var milliseconds = date.getMilliseconds();
if (milliseconds < 10) {
  milliseconds = '00' + milliseconds;
} else if (milliseconds < 100) {
  milliseconds = '0' + milliseconds;
}
TIME_FORMAT = hours + ':' + minutes + ':' + seconds + ',' + milliseconds;

console.log(TIME_FORMAT);
```